# Styling a json list

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

how do i style my json list to material cards?

My json/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var url="getjson.php";

     $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data.bananas, function(i,post){ 
            var banana =

             "<div>"
      +"<h3>"+post.name+"</h3>"
        +"<h5>"+post.type+"</h5>"
      +"</div>";

      $(banana).appendTo("#banana-data");
      });
```

now im trying to display it as a nicelt style list of cards but im struggling:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <div id="banana-data" class="box box-widget widget-user">
             <div class="widget-user-header bg-aqua-active">
              <h3 class="widget-user-username"></h3>
              <h5 class="widget-user-desc"></h5>

                   </div>
            </div>
      </div>      
  </div>
```

But my content appears outside the style of my 
I tried using list as follows:

```
         <ol id="banana-data">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <div  class="box box-widget widget-user">
             <div class="widget-user-header bg-aqua-active">
              <h3 class="widget-user-username"></h3>
              <h5 class="widget-user-desc"></h5>

                   </div>
            </div>
      </div>      
  </div>  
    </ol>


          var banana =

         "<ol>"
  +"<h3>"+post.cname+"</h3>"
    +"<h5>"+post.sub_type+"</h5>"
  +"</ol>";

  $(banana).appendTo("#banana-data");
  });
```

The content displayed inside my style,but the entire list of items in the json file was sitting on the same card,and not separating to create multiple styled cards.

this is my php file that converted the data in the msqli table to json:

```
    <?php

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    $posts = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bananas";

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $posts['bananas'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($posts);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not append it.You have to use `after()` method like this..

```
 $("#banana-data").after(banana);
```

So change your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var url="getjson.php";

     $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      console.log(data);
        banana = "";
      $.each(data.bananas, function(i,post){ 
            banana +=

             "<div>"
      +"<h3>"+post.name+"</h3>"
        +"<h5>"+post.type+"</h5>"
      +"</div>";
      });
    $("#banana-data").after(banana);
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried this,but the list of items still appears outside the style.

Comment: i copied your answer exactly as it is,but content still appears outside the style

Comment: `$("#banana-data .row  .col-md-4").after(banana)` what about like this?

Comment: using that makes all the content dissapear behind the style.Its not visible

Comment: jsfiddle does not support my database,but this is the link:https://jsfiddle.net/AngelaDutchan/aoavakc0/  im usilg localhost and the json is generated by a php file.The content from the mysqli db is converted to json.

Comment: i think you have to add code after class="box box-widget widget-user"

Comment: Still no luck.The text styles perfectly,alingment is perfect,but content still appears outside of my background style card:<div class="box box-widget widget-user"

Comment: could you maybe send me links to tutorials about parsing json etc..i am willing to watch videos or read to get this done

Comment: And "lodge +=" has not been assigned a type...should it not be var lodge +=?

Comment: Please vote my question..i need points to be able to share images and chat

Comment: can not use var lodge += because var keyword makes variable as local which can not accessed from outside.

Comment: can not use var lodge += because var keyword makes variable as local which can not accessed from outside the function.

Comment: yes if you got help feel free to vote up and tick mark answer.thanks

Comment: try first ..don't worry i will help.

Comment: ok,Thanks alot .I appreciate it..i am still pushing hard to find a solution,by elimination.Theres probably an issue with my styling.This works well in a regular table though     <div class="table-responsive">
        
         <table id="banana-data" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>id</th>
            </tr>
            </table>
        
        </div>

Comment: oho yes you have to more `</div>s` before closing `</ol>`.

Answer (score 0):

Very Good Question:
There are multiple libraries you can use for parsing and styling json:
[Handlebars is a library that allows you to parse your json with ease and include each json object in your html](http://handlebarsjs.com)

The other one is Moustache.But my solution for you is handlebars.
First turn your json into an actual jsonfile as follows...

```
$json_data = json_encode($posts);
file_put_contents('ldt.json', $json_data);
```

Add those two lines in your php instead of your echo.ldt is the filename,you can call it whatever you want.

Nextstep:parse the json file using handlebars..

```
var yourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
yourRequest.open('GET', 'ldt.json');
```

Then in handlebars on create a function and..instruct handlebars to generate html(myhtml) of parsed json and assign it to an id called:eg mycontainer:

```
var rawTemplate = document.getElementById("thisTemplate").innerHTML;
        var myContainer = document.getElementById("my-container");
      my.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
```

Then in your html:

```
<div id="my-container"></div>

 <script id="thisTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
//And here call your objects:Example

     {{#each bananas}}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="box box-widget widget-user">
               <div class="widget-user-header bg-black" style="background: url('{{img}}'>) center center;">
     <h3 class="widget-user-username"><b>{{name}}</b></h3>
    <h5 class="widget-user-desc">({{type}})</h5>
```

Just make sure your css actually creates your so called cards etc..and your card list will populate your page exactly as you have styled it with all the objects youve parsed.
Ive simply added small snippets of code.For more information,check out:
[Handlebars](http://handlebars.com)

Theres nothing wrong with just using ajax and create your own elements,but if you want to kill two birds with one stone,use libraries.
There are also alot of tuts on youtube you can watch.I hope this helps